# Pressing Enter button on keyboard will open another instance of popup modal

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, modal-dialog

I have an issue when I press enter on a popup modal then another instance of that modal will appear. Each Enter action opens another Modal on top of the previous one.  But it does not happen when I press enter in the  box search box just if I press enter anywhere else on the modal. How do I stop this happening?

```
<div class="form-group text-right" data-bind="if: state   enter code here== 'Template'">
    <label class="visible-xs">
        Supplier Ref
    </label>
    <label class="hidden-xs">
        Supplier Order Reference
    </label>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <span id="supplierReference"       databind="text:supplierOrderReference() || '-'"></span>       
        <!-- ko ifnot: isReadOnly() || orderIsLocked()-->
        <a id="changeSupplierReferenceLink" class="hidden-print" href="#" title="Click to change the supplier reference" data-bind="visible: user().canEditSupplierReference(), click: changeSupplierReference">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <img class="barcode" alt="" height="20" data-bind="visible: supplierOrderReference, attr: { src: barcodeUrl }" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont see any key press event to support your question, try to add actual code where problem is.
Also try _event.stopPropogation_ if the is problem of event bubbling.